# How do i show modalViewController or navigationController? (iPhone SDK)

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, modalviewcontroller

I'm trying to show a login page for an app I'm creating but I can't seem to get the navigation controller to activate.

```
- (IBAction)startSignin:(id)sender {
    Login *aview = [[Login alloc] init];
    aview.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;

    [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:aview animated:YES];
    [aview release];
}
```

How do i get it to show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will never show unless you the view is already added as a `subview` of `UIWindow`, which I am assuming is not the case.

Comment: I figured it out but why do I always get a SIGABRT or EXEC_BAD_ACCESS?